# Direction of wind

Tags: logical-deduction, geography, situation

On a bright and sunny day, in a small town, a large balloon (such as is usually used for advertising/promotional purposes of brands/products) is floating high in the air, tied with a rope on the ground.

Look at a schematic picture below:

[image]

In the afternoon, the balloon -- which can be seen from any point in the town -- appeared to be as shown in the picture, with its rope tight (in full tension). In such a case, what are all the possible directions in which wind at the surroundings of the balloon can flow?

Comment: Can I politely remind you of what I said [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/54660/recursive-questions-answers#comment168712_54660)? About spending a bit more time and putting a bit more effort into your posts? You know have 93 posts yet not one of them has a higher than 6...

Comment: You currently have an average score of 1 per post. That is the 11th lowest across the entire site. While I don't want to stop participating here - I think you need to stop posting so much and start putting some effort into making better puzzles and making sure your answers are high quality too. It would make this site a better place if you did...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For everyone in town to see the balloon that way,

> It must not be deflected by the wind in any direction at all or some viewers would see its tether at an angle. Assuming as I am that the intent of the diagram is to show that the tether is visible and straight up for all viewers, this means there can be zero net wind laterally on the balloon.
>  The only really feasible way for this to happen is if there is no wind at all.  The only other possibilities are wind coming directly upward from the ground, or wind striking the balloon from opposing directions and in matching strength, neither of which are physically probable.

Comment: ^vote with a note: The foliated tree allows another (somewhat rare) [possibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wind_shear) . . .